# VHDL: Problem with unexpected IF

Tags: vhdl

Hello I am trying to learn VHDL in xilinx ISE enviroment and I can not get this code to work and i do not know why. I have tried single quotes using/not using ands, but nothing works. Could someone please help me?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

---- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
---- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity teh_3 is
    Port ( thermo_input : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
           too_hot : out  STD_LOGIC;
           too_cold : out  STD_LOGIC;
           just_right : out  STD_LOGIC);
end teh_3;

architecture Behavioral of teh_3 is

begin

IF thermo_input < "1000" THEN
  too_cold <='1' and
  too_hot <='0' and
  just_right <='0';
ELSIF thermo_input > "1011" THEN 
    too_hot <='1' and
    too_cold <='0' and
    just_right <='0';
ELSIF thermo_input > "0111" THEN 
  just_right <='1' and
  too_hot <='0' and
  too_cold <='0';
ELSE
  just_right <='0' and
  too_hot <='0' and
  too_cold <='0';
END IF;
```

end Behavioral;

`ERROR:HDLParsers:164 - "/home/student/kokeilu/kokeil.vhd" Line 40. parse error, unexpected IF`

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Fundamentally, you can't use if outside of a process.

Also, don't use `std_logic_arith`, use `numeric_std` - http://parallelpoints.com/node/3

---

To fix, make a process, or use the proper combinatorial syntax as suggested by patrick.

The way you have it currently it will have to be a *combinatorial process*, so be careful to get *all* your inputs in the sensitivity list or use the new VHDL-2008 `process(all)` syntax.  Depends on which version of ISE you are using as to whether that is supported.

Or make it a synchronous process - this is how most code for FPGAs is written.

Add a `clk` input to your entity and then put your `if/elsif/else` code inside a synchronous process:

```
process (clk)
begin
  if thermo_input < "1000" then
   .... etc
end process;
```

Finally, you don't use `AND` to make several things happen at once:

```
IF thermo_input < "1000" THEN
  too_cold <='1'; -- semicolons here, not ANDs!
  too_hot <='0';
  just_right <='0';
```

is the right way!

Answer (score 2):

An `if` can only be used inside a process. You can use a WHEN instead or you have to create a process. I Should go for the when statement, which looks like this.

#### Example:

```
too_cold   <= '1' WHEN (thermo_input < "1000") ELSE '0';
too_hot    <= '1' WHEN (thermo_input > "1011") ELSE '0';
just_right <= '1' WHEN (thermo_input > "0111" AND thermo_input < "1011") ELSE '0';
```

I didn't test it, but this is to give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You should also be careful with `thermo_input > "0111"`

Make sure you think twice about what "0111" represents. Is it a signed or unsigned 4 bit integer?
I recommend to make this explicit. Library 'numeric_std' contains a lot of helpful methods.